# Need explanation on creating utf-8 encoded files on linux using c++

Tags: c++, linux, encoding, utf-8

I need some explanations on encodage of files using g++ on Linux.

I have an easy code :

```
int main ()
{
  FILE * pFile;
  char buffer[] = { 'x' , 'y' , 'z' ,'é' };
  pFile = fopen ("myfile", "wt, ccs=UTF-8");
  //pFile = fopen ("myfile", "wt");
  fwrite (buffer , sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), pFile);
  fclose (pFile);
  return 0;
}
```

Even if the  "ccs=UTF-8" part is added on the fopen line, the output file of this program is always encoded in iso-8859-1. However, if I create a file using vi on Linux containing theses charaters, the resulting file is UTF-8 encoded (I use the command "file myfile" to see the encoding mode of the file, and a "xxd -b myfile" confirm this behavior).

So I would like to undestand :

1- Why g++ on Linux doesn't create a UTF-8 file by default?

2- What is the aim of the ccs=UTF-8 if the file created is not encoded in UTF-8?

3- How can I create an UTF-8 file based on this simple code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file may appear to be in ISO-8859-1, but it's actually not. It's simply broken.

Your file contains byte `A9`, which is the lower byte of UTF-8 representation of `é`.

When you wrote `'é'`, the compiler should have warned you:

```
 aaa.c:4:38: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
     char buffer[] = { 'x' , 'y' , 'z' ,'é' };
                                         ^
```

`char` is not a type for a character, it's a type for one byte. GCC treats multibyte character literals as big-endian integers. Here, you cast it immediately to `char`, leaving the lowest byte: `A9`

(BTW, `é` in ISO-8859-1 is `E9`, not `A9`)

You open your file with an encoding, but then you save **bytes** into it. The bytes correspond to ISO-8859-1 characters `xyz©`.

If you want to write characters, not bytes, then use `wchar_t` instead of `char` and `fputws` instead of `fwrite`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main ()
{
  FILE * pFile;
  // note final zero and L indicating wchar_t literal
  wchar_t buffer[] = { 'x' , 'y' , 'z' , L'é' , 0};
  // note no space before ccs
  pFile = fopen ("myfile", "wt,ccs=UTF-8");
  fputws(buffer, pFile);
  fclose (pFile);
  return 0;
}
```